# Difference between DataFlow and Pipelines

Tags: azure-data-factory

I do not understand the difference between dataflow and pipeline in Azure Data Factory.

I have read and see DataFlow can Transform Data without writing any line of code.

But I have made a pipeline and this is exactly the same thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A Pipeline is an orchestrator and does not transform data. It manages a series of one or more activities, such as Copy Data or Execute Stored Procedure. Data Flow is one of these activity types and is very different from a Pipeline.

Data Flow performs row and column level transformations, such as parsing values, calculations, adding/renaming/deleting columns, even adding or removing rows. At runtime a Data Flow is executed in a Spark environment, not the Data Factory execution runtime.

A Pipeline can run without a Data Flow, but a Data Flow cannot run without a Pipeline.

Comment: Substitute "pipeline" for "control flow", if you're familiar with SSIS and it might become clearer

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, dataflow activity need to be executed in the pipeline. So I suspect that you are talking about the copy activity and dataflow activity as both of them are used for transferring data from source to sink.

> I have read and see DataFlow can Transform Data without writing any
>   line of code.

Your could see the [overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview) of Data Flow. Data flow allows data engineers to develop graphical data transformation logic without writing code. All data transfer steps are based on visual interfaces.

> I have made a pipeline and this is exactly the same thing.

Copy activity could be used for data transmission. However, it has many [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#alternative-column-mapping) with column mapping. So,if you just need simple and pure data transmission, Copy Activity could be used. In order to further meet the personalized needs, you could find many [built-in features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-transformation-overview) in the Data Flow Activity. For example, Derived column, Aggregate,Sort etc.