# How to write expression in expression builder in data flow of ADF

Tags: regex, azure, azure-data-factory

I need an expression in the expression builder to transform the customer Name as below
Take first character of word in the name followed by * . Customer name may contain 1 or more words
Name can be Tim or Tim John or Tim John Zac or Tim John Mike Zac

Comment: 'Take first character of word in the name followed by *', can you provide a sample expected result. you want the rows of the column Customer Name which starts with a word right? If thats the case you can use `startswith()` to filter the required records.

Comment: @RakeshGovindula Eg: Tim as T***** and Tim John as T*****J***** and Tim John Zac as T*****J*****Z*****

Comment: If you want to do it dynamically, how do you know that start letter of every word which we need to give in the condition?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula Is there any expression to take the first character of every word and replace the other characters with '*'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced above and got below results using derived column.

I have used the same data that you have given in a single column and used the below dataflow expression in derived column.

```
dropLeft(toString(reduce(map(split(Name, ' '),regexReplace(#item, concat('[^',left(#item,1),']'), '*')), '', #acc +  '  '  + #item, #result)), 2)
```

Here, some general regular expressions were given errors for me in dataflow, that's why used the above approach.

First, I have used `split()` by `space` to get an array of strings. Then used regular expression on every item of array like above.

As we do not have `join` in dataflow expression, I have used the code from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75089327) by **@Jarred Jobe** to convert array to a string seperated by spaces.

**Result:**

[image]

**NOTE:**

Make sure you give two spaces in `toString()` of above code to get the required result. If we give only one space it will give the results like below.

[image]

**Update:**

> Thank you so much for sharing this. I have tried your solution but I
> got few names wrong .Also I want to replace the rest of the characters
> with just 5 '*' irrespective of how many characters the name has. Also
> name : Mia hellah came as M** h****h instead of M***** h*****. Another
> one SAM & JOHN TIBEH should be S***** &***** J***** T*****. I tried to
> update your expression but I couldn't get it right.

If you want to do like above, you can directly use `concat` function dataflow expression.

```
dropLeft(toString(reduce(map(split(Name, ' '),concat(left(#item,1), '*****')), '', #acc +  '  '  + #item, #result)), 2)
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this. I have tried your solution but I got few names wrong .Also I want to replace the rest of the characters with just 5 '*' irrespective of how many characters the name has. Also name : Mia hellah came as  M** h****h instead of M***** h*****. Another one SAM & JOHN TIBEH should be S***** &***** J***** T*****. I tried to update your expression but I couldn't get it right.

Comment: @Jen, I have updated my answer as per your requirement, please check that.

Comment: Wow it worked!! Thank you so much for your answer. Highly appreciate your support :)

Comment: Just a query whether adf pipeline copy activity allow these expressions ? I mean whether I can achieve the same while copy the data from one Azure Table storage to another

Comment: ADF pipeline Copy activity is not designed to perform the activities like above which involves rows and column level operations. its better use dataflows for this. Refer this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62015027/difference-between-dataflow-and-pipelines) to understand more.