# Azure Data Factory equivalent to SSIS 'data conversion transformation' task?

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I'm wondering if anyone familiar with Azure data factory can help me figure this out. In SSIS I use the "data conversion transformation" task. It might be staring me right in the face, but I can't find the equivalent task in azure data factory. Anyone know? TY

I've looked through all of the ADF tasks available and none seem to cover data conversion.

Comment: Data factory and SSIS are quite different from each other. It sounds like you want a Data Flow activity - check out this answer for a bit more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62015027/difference-between-dataflow-and-pipelines/62023779#62023779

Comment: Thanks- I am using a data flow activity. What I don't know is what task I can drag into this data flow to do a data conversion. There are many equivalent tasks such as derived column, but I just don't see a data conversion tasks like in SSIS. I can't imagine there isn't a way to do this but so far nothing has turned up with google.

Comment: Use Derived Column to either create new columns [by specifying a new column name] or update/replace existing columns [by specifying an existing column name].

Comment: What kind of data conversion do you want to perform in data flow? Could you share sample input and output data?

Answer (score 0):

That is either the Mapping dataflow activity or PowerQuery activity depending on what you want to do. If your goal is ETL/ELT then its dataflow either in ADF or Synapse pipelines (they are the same thing essentially).  The activity you talked about in SSIS essentially changes the datatype of the column and copies to another column, for example int64 into float.

In ADF mapping dataflow, this transformation is called Cast under Schema modifiers, influenced by the spark logic:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-cast

Here is a nice video i found:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUX4ALdBbvA

Comment: thank you, this solved it! please upvote anyone who sees this

Comment: @SeaQwell, Glad I was able to help you!