# About pricing Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, data-integration

I've been reading a lot the pricing table of Azure Synapse ([here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/synapse-analytics/#pricing)). Let's suppose I have running a process "all day", with de default IR which correspond to 8 VCores.

So, making the calculations result on:

[image]

Since DIU per hour is 0,25USD, I have 0,25 USD * 24 per day * 30 per month, resulting in 180 USD per month.

In the other hand,

[image]

Asuming the default basic IR mentioned above, I have 0,257 USD * 8 VCores * 24 hours per day * 30 days in one month, resulting in 1.480 USD

am I right in these calculations? Azure Synapse will cost at least 1.480 + 180 = 1.660 USD/month

The others costs, I think, are almost neglilible.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

While your math looks correct, I would share a few thoughts.

1. You only pay for actual runtime, not the 24x7x30 model you presented. If your solution requires an "always running" pipeline, I would say it needs to be rearchitected.
2. Data Flow is an [activity inside a pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62015027/difference-between-dataflow-and-pipelines/62023779#62023779), but its underlying runtime is Spark, so the costs are higher. You should definitely never have an "always running" Data Flow.

Comment: What I mean with "all day" is to have a pipeline running a dataflow every 3 mins, let's say... just an example. I know if I wanted a always running job in a realtime fashion, Stram Analytics is the solution.

My point here is pricing a Synapse solution. As far I know, in my example, the second cost I exposed reflects Spark (the default IR on 8 VCores VM), so I'm considering (I think) the dataflow pricing already.

Comment: The Spark pool for the Data Flow can take several minutes to spin up, so running a data flow every three minutes could be problematic. You can mitigate this with a custom IR and a "Time to Live" setting, but you would then be effectively paying 24x7 for Data Flow.

Comment: I repeat again, I'm not asking about architectural opinions. Mi concern is about how to price Synapse right, If I had a dataflow running, instead, every 10 minutes ...

Mi concern is about what I exposed in my question and rationale wether is right or wrong

Comment: So my calculations seem to be right ... aren't they?